# Поле enum vs varchar, конвертация в mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица в которой есть поле типа `enum`, появилась задача поменять работу с этим полем и решили сделать его `varchar`.

При попытке поменять тип поля все записанные в таблице в данном поле значения заменяются на пустоту, а предполагалось что значения сохранятся.

Это я что то делаю не так, или прямой сменой типа тут не обойтись?

Comment: 1) создаете дополнительное поле varchar; 2) вносите в него значения, соответствующие enum; 3) удаляете enum; 4) переименовываете поле. Так пойдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

внутри столбца типа *enum* хранятся не строки, а числа, что хорошо демонстрирует второй запрос, приведённый ниже.

а сами строки хранятся в описании таблицы (см. запрос номер три).

пример «преобразования» тоже приведён (ненужный столбец после этого можно удалить, а новосозданный — переименовать):

```
alter table t add column v text;
update t set v=e;
```

результаты видны в четвёртом запросе.

p.s. я использовал тип *text*, а не *varchar*, что в данном случае не играет роли.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ccf1/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (e enum('раз','два','три'));

insert into t values
   ('три')
  ,('раз')
  ,('два')
  ,(1)
;

alter table t add column v text;

update t set v=e;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select e from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ccf1/2/0)**:

```
|   e |
|-----|
| три |
| раз |
| два |
| раз |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select e+0 from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ccf1/2/1)**:

```
| e+0 |
|-----|
|   3 |
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   1 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
show columns from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ccf1/2/2)**:

```
| COLUMN_NAME |             COLUMN_TYPE | IS_NULLABLE | COLUMN_KEY | COLUMN_DEFAULT | EXTRA |
|-------------|-------------------------|-------------|------------|----------------|-------|
|           e | enum('раз','два','три') |         YES |            |         (null) |       |
|           v |                    text |         YES |            |         (null) |       |
```

**Query 4**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ccf1/2/3)**:

```
|   e |   v |
|-----|-----|
| три | три |
| раз | раз |
| два | два |
| раз | раз |
```